# PHP mongoDB list users with same field value

Tags: php, mongodb

Using PHP and MongoClient, I'm trying to figure out how to list users in one organization.

I can list all users from all organizations, but I only want to list users from one organization.

How do I filter the documents like this?

My document structure is simple:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56fd6a77768d8864028b4578"),
    "name" : "Jack Daniels",
    "email" : "jackdaniels@janes-jeans.com",
    "manager" : "John doe",
    "password" : "$2y$10$cec5pzCghhhRdwPVnT/t4.EssfIbqighVqpZSa3jWPRV4gdfXUGDu",
    "organization" : "Jane's Jeans"
}
```

Here is my code where I'm trying to only get results related to one organization:

```
<optgroup label="Employees">
<?php
     $cursor = $collection->find($curr_org);
     foreach($cursor as $curr_org) {
          echo '<option name="name">';
               echo $curr_org['name'];
          echo '</option>';
     }
?>
</optgroup>
```

$curr_org contains the organization name.

Removing $curr_org from find() displays all user from all organizations.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass proper argument to `->find`:

```
$cursor = $collection->find(['organization' => $curr_org]);
```

For more details you can check out [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php)

Comment: Thanks for getting back @malarzm. I get a syntax error and an empty result when I use this. I previously tried similar $cursor = $collection->find($curr_org['organization']); which does not give a syntax error, but also gives an empty result. What I find odd is that I can echo $curr_org['organization']; and do get the single organization. I'll take a look at your link and try other variations.

Comment: Got it! $cursor = $collection->find(array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'])); Thanks for the hint @malarzm, you got me on the right track.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you have newer PHP version installed :) Offhand you should update it as 5.3 is not supported for quite some time now

Comment: ???? Here is my PHP version: root@lrs:~# php -v
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2015 01:34:46)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies

Comment: One side question... relative to the $cursor, do you know the !exists syntax I would use to clear records with empty values. I'm currently lost with this as well. I've been trying to use the {!exists => false} in the find command, but it does nothing. Sorry finding and filtering are what I'm currently learning in PHP Mongo.

Comment: Disregard, I got it... $cursor = $collection->find(array("organization" => $curr_org['organization'], "name" => array('$exists' => true)));

Comment: Ahh sorry, thought that syntax error came from my `[...]` as you posted code with `array(...)` and said it worked then. Anyways glad you sorted it out!